# How to test the WKdm algorithm against buffers of various sizes in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to test the WKdm algorithm to see how well it performs against buffers of 100KB, 1MB, and 10MB; however, any buffer greater than 1KB in my test program below throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS:Could not access memory.

I took WKdm.c's main(), which is a simple test, and tried to convert it so that i could change the size of the input buffer to be compressed.

I'm using the standard Scott Kaplan implementation of the WKDM algorithm which consists of a source and header file, found [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~sfkaplan/research/compressed-caching/WKdm.tgz&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEgwxY6HJxWUO21I8l2Uz6b7lrI4Q).  I have tried on Linux and OS X 32-bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "WKdm.h"

#define PAGE_SIZE_IN_WORDS 1024
#define PAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES 4096

int main() {

    WK_word i;
    //int testSize = 1024; //1KB Works
    int testSize = 102400; //100KB causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    int testNumWords = testSize / sizeof(WK_word);
    printf("testSize = %d bytes or %d words\n", testSize, testNumWords);

    WK_word* source_buf = (WK_word*) malloc(testSize * 2);
    WK_word* dest_buf = (WK_word*) malloc(testSize * 2);
    WK_word* udest_buf = (WK_word*) malloc(testSize * 2);

    for (i = 0; i < testNumWords; i++) {
        source_buf[i] = rand() % 1000; //Semi-random: 0-999 stored in each 4-byte word
    }

    source_buf[testNumWords + 1] = 99999;
    udest_buf[testNumWords + 1] = 55555;

    printf("first 50 words of source_buf are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        printf(" %d", source_buf[i]);
    fflush(stdout);

    struct timeval t0;  struct timeval t1;
    gettimeofday(&t0, 0);

    // Compress the source_buf into the dest_buf
    i = WKdm_compress(source_buf, dest_buf, testNumWords);

    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
    long elapsed = (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec;

    printf("\nWKdm_compress size in bytes: %u\n", i);
    printf("Time to compress: %lu microseconds\n\n", elapsed);

    printf("redzone value at end of source buf (should be 99999) is %u\n",
            source_buf[testNumWords + 1]); fflush(stdout);

    gettimeofday(&t0, 0);

    WKdm_decompress(dest_buf, udest_buf, testNumWords);

    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
    elapsed = (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec;
    printf("Time to decompress: %lu microseconds\n\n", elapsed);

    printf("redzone value at end of udest buf (should be 55555) is %u\n", udest_buf[testSize + 1]);

    printf("first 50 words of udest_buf are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        printf(" %d", udest_buf[i]);

    i = bcmp(source_buf, udest_buf, 100);

    printf("\nbcmp of orig. and compr'd/decompr'd copy (should be 0) is %u\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `WK_word* source_buf = (WK_word*) malloc(testSize * 2);` where does the `2` come from ? Hint: sizeof is your friend.

Comment: How is WK_word defined? What wildpasser is telling you is do this  WK_word* source_buf = malloc(testSize * sizeof(WK_word)); etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your comments. WK_word is a 4 byte unsigned long int. I multiplied by two so that I could test the bufs to ensure nothing is copied past the expected boundaries. The original code sample does it the same way. See how the word past udest_buf[testNumWords] is set to 55555, and then validated at the end after uncompressing and storing the original data into udest_buf. I totally agree with the use of sizeof, but in this case I extended beyond sizeof(WK_word) for validation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WKdm algorithm as implemented by Scott Kaplan was designed for a page size of 4KB.  If you want to compress anything greater than 4KB, you need to increase the sizes of the arrays that are used to hold the output data in intermediate form during modeling.  These 3 arrays are found at the top of the WKdm_compress and WKdm_decompress functions.  You can increase their sizes to store more intermediate data, but it appears the comp/decomp time increases dramatically.

Also, compressing a buffer greater than 1MB caused more out of bounds exceptions for me.  So unless you want to do a fair amount of rewrite, you may want to just use WKdm for buffers of less than 4KB.

As a side note, the fact that Kaplan's WKdm implementation is optimized for compressing 4KB is probably a big reason why Apple is using it for memory compression in OS X 10.9 Mavericks, which has a page size of 4KB.